# Cannot debug React Native with Android Studio

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to debug react native in vscode or chrome there is an issue.  When I run the debugger in  chrome and reload the app.  I get an error saying debugging connection was closed. I also can't open the dev menu in android studio after an error.
I'm using the following code to test debugging:

```
export default function App() {
  let x;
  x.toString();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have tried debugging in chrome and vs code.  I'm expecting the code to stop on exceptions and debug points, but it does not.